# How to detect end of range object while searching in word document in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have programmatically define range object in word document. Now I am trying to search perticular word in this range, but my search is going beyond the range object. how do I restrict my search within the range.
below is code snippet

```
WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(<Text to find>) ' To set start of range
StartRng = WordApp.Selection.Start
    With WordApp.Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
    End With

    WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(<Text to find>) ' To set end of range
    EndRng = WordApp.Selection.End

    WordRng = WordDoc.Range(Start:=StartRng, [End]:=EndRng)
    WordRng.Select()

    With WordRng.Find
        .Text = "CR"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
    End With
    WordRng.Find.Execute()

    Do While WordRng.Find.Found = True
        Console.WriteLine(WordRng.Text)
        WordRng.Find.Execute()
        CRCount += 1
    Loop
```

this Do while loop Finds the text "CR" beyond the selected range.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code causes the issue you faced with:

```
 .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
```

The [Wrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192810(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Find class returns or sets what happens if the search begins at a point other than the beginning of the document and the end of the document is reached (or vice versa if Forward is set to False) or if the search text isn't found in the specified selection or range.